# is it harmful to use "volatile" in C?

Tags: c, kernel, volatile, sparse-matrix

I am very new to Sparse. And During running sparse I am seeing this warning:

warning: incorrect type in argument 2 (different address spaces)

```
expected void volatile [noderef] <asn:2>*addr
got void *
```

Basically, This is happening because of following:

```
struct context{
    void __iomem *base;
};

readl(const volatile void __iomem* add){
....
....
}

function: foo(){
    struct  context *var;
    readl(var->base);   //---> here i got the above mentioned warning
}
```

TO fix this I did following:

```
struct context{
      - void __iomem *base;
      + volatile void __iomem *base;
};
```

And warning get removed.

**My question:**
           - is it harmful to use "volatile" in such case. and if yes then WHY?
           - What I think is that I should not make the member of struct as "volatile". But, then how we can get rid off from the Csparse warning.

As per the documentation given @ https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/volatile-considered-harmful.txt
@ http://lwn.net/Articles/233482/.
we should always avoid the use of volatile.

Comment: The linked articles state that `volatile` is useless **for concurrency control**. Both give examples where it can be legitimately used.

Comment: This line: struct  context *var;
    readl(var->base);  is reading into the address contained in var, However, var is only a pointer, not any actual place to be putting data.  Perhaps change to struct context var, to create an actual instance of the struct, the change readl(var->base) to the following two lines: var.base = malloc( desired max size );  readl(var.base);

Comment: @user3629249. No, I don't think that would be right solution. As malloc() returns the (void*), which is different address space location with respect to __iomem * location.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not harmful. No idea why it should or could be, harmful to what?

If the code you're calling expects a `volatile` pointer, then it's incorrect to pass a non-`volatile` one, since the code in the calling context might not be properly adapted to the requirements of a  `volatile` value in that case.

Comment: is it somewhere related to __iomem macro also ?

# define __iomem        __attribute__((noderef, address_space(2)))


because in warning message it is mentioned (different address space).
I think sparse should not report: "different address space" because 
data itself is also declared as "__iomem".

As far as I know it should report the "different address space" in case when member data of struct context is void *base (not void __iomem* base).

Answer (score 1):

volatile instructs the compiler not to do any optimization for that variable. Thus, it would provide guarantee that  the latest value of variable to use. This may be altered by an external event.
volatile is generally used when dealing with external events, like interrupts of hardware related pins.
I don't think, it's harmful. But why should one use when not needed, because optimization helps in better efficiency, so if you are sure that even if the variable is optimized, it cannot be altered by external event, then fine, no volatile then.

Comment: But how can we ensure that a particular variable is not being altered by external event.
What i know; we can use locking mechanism ??
But if it so, then why we needed  the "volatile" datatype. since we can also avoid the optimization using locking mechanism.
please correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: @AmitKumarSharma if you have single thread applications, then you know who is accessing your variables, must be within your own program, right? For mutltihreaded applications, you need synchronizations nd mutual exclusions to access shared variables. And there is interrupt that could cause change in some of your variables, right?

Comment: Right. in multi-threaded  environment, we need synchronization. But making variable **volatile** as shared and  keeping it inside critical section is waste. Because under these circumstance behavior of volatile is not preserved.
Compiler would also be prevented from optimizing access
to shared_data within the critical section, when we know that nobody else can be working with it.  While the lock is held, shared_data is not volatile.  When dealing with shared data, proper locking makes volatile is unnecessary.
Then why we need volatile.

Comment: @AmitKumarSharma Compiler cannot decide on the runtime or dynamic behavior, right? Sometimes, it may so happen that depending on some condition, you access the shared variable and lock otherwise use something else, how can compiler decide that?